# Error of VM is shown while build apk

Tags: hybrid

this error is shown while making the apk 
  the whole program is run properly but comile the apk version for my app than it shown me this type of error message.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM1m1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enought ram to start your VM with the given configuiration ( just check the error message ). Change he amount of memory should help you here.